# Proxy an oracle connection without ssh?

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, proxy

I'd like to develop on a dev computer which makes a jdbc connection to a proxy machine connected to the corporate VPN, which in turn makes a connection to the corporate database.

I have a computer connected to the corporate VPN, running an oracle client. Its tnsnames.ora has something like:

```
### PROXY MACHINE IP 192.16.100.20 ###
CORP_DB= (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host=server.corp.com)(Port= 1525))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CORP_DB)))
```

Would it be possible to have a dev machine proxy through the VPN's machine's connection? I.e. the dev machine's tnsnames.ora would look like

```
## DEV MACHINE IP 192.16.100.30 ###
PROXY= (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host=192.16.100.20)(Port= 1525))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = PROXY)))
```

The dev machine would make jdbc connections to a URL:     jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.16.100.20:1525:PROXY

If proxying through a client wouldn't work, could one setup an Oracle server instance on the proxy machine, which just forwards requests through to the corporate database on the VPN? Something like a listener?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure [Oracle Connection Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10775/cman.htm) on the machine that is on the VPN and use that as a proxy.

It seems unlikely that the corporate security folks would be particularly happy with this solution-- they generally don't want you to set up services that let non-VPN'd machines access resources behind the VPN because that circumvents some of the security that the VPN provides.  If this is a large (or particularly security conscious) organization, they're probably periodically looking to see if VPN'd machines have services that are listening on ports (like Connection Manager would) and would red-flag such a service.  Corporate security would generally suggest that you either VPN in to the corporate network on your actual development machine or that you develop on the machine that is on the VPN.